# Why won't my washing machine dry my clothes?

Tags: washing-machine

Please my washing machine washes clothes but do not dry them?

Washing machine: Arthur Martin 500T AW 575 electrolux

The program is blocked on the value 4, it passes from 3 to 4 correctly but from 4 to 5 it's blocked (from 4 to 5 it dry the clothes).

When it wants drying, it's blocked and emits noise. I try to empty myself the water, I reboot and it dry correctly so I think this is an absorption problem?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't do its spin cycle?

Comment: yes it doesn't do its spin cycle;does not absorb water and does not dry. thank you for help

Comment: And does its timer keep moving?

Comment: no it stopped, and the machine makes a noise

Comment: Does it have a dry-only setting, and what happens if you use that setting?

Comment: usually it washes clothes and then dry. but this week she washes the clothes  but not dry , it remains blocked on the value 4 and produces a lot of noise, it does not absorb water,

Comment: i have never used on dry-only, I act only on the program (from 3 to 4 the machine washes then it passes from 4 to 5 to dry clothes, this week it passes from 3 to 4 ans it's blocked on 4

Comment: when it wants drying, it's blocked and emits noise, so I try to empty myself the water, I reboot and it dry correctly so I think this is an absorption problem?? have you an idea please ? i'll attach an images in my question

Comment: i want to insert images of my machine but: We're sorry, but as a spam prevention mechanism, new users aren't allowed to post images. Earn more than 10 reputation to post images.!!!!

Comment: @researcher please see the [faq]. Before you have 10 reputation, you can include a url and we'll inline the image for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the drain pump

Comment: Do you have more details about how you identified the problem and what was required to repair it? Without that, this Q&A will be of little use to others in the future.

Comment: i contact a specialist and he managed the problem, he have he changed one of the parts of the pump, the lower part of the pump, this piece costs 40$
He said that the cause is: the machine is old